# Is a meter constantly getting bigger?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang, distance, length

If the bigbang is the start of the expansion of space *everywhere* then does that mean that a 1 meter ruler is bigger tomorrow than it was today?

Does this apply to the size of atomic particles and cells and everything? If so, how can we know that space is expanding? just because we measure things far away so it takes time?

If everything is getting bigger at the same rate does that mean that it has no overall effect? or can you outrun the effect?

sorry for the somewhat incoherent question, it's hard to form a good question when I'm not sure on so many aspects of this. Hopefully someone can fill in my apparent gaps in knowledge,

Answer (score 0):

the Hubble expansion rate is measurable only on cosmic distance scales, trillions of times bigger than a meter stick. The forces that hold nuclei and atoms together on the micro scale are gigantically bigger than the forces that drive cosmic expansion on the ultramacro scale- so the dimensions of atoms don't change, but the distance between galaxies does.